# Connecting conversational AI to Alexa

Tags: json, alexa-skills-kit, sap-conversational-ai

I built my Conversational AI chatbot and followed all the steps to connect it to Alexa but when I try to call my chatbot in alexa simulator,I get the following message:

"There was a problem with the requested skill's response"

[image]

this is the code which appears on JSON output 1 and JSON output 2 after the error:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.5e3bb3da-ba51-4422-80cb-c5cace7e3756",
    "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.bfb81ac5-d463-4201-b70c-a35f8cc6dbed"
    },
    "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AHIAWE37M4SE4Q7DBFIIRLYZYXFKPU42HAD35P5XLHMZA4RGRXFERFRKPAN2I34A56TCC2XEGVNKYH7SW2KVB2NBUYAAY73GRDDXNEFFFY46W2FJXXCLSMAIUWDEUESU3ZMGIYPPYA2WXFXBBHGJBLHNVRYBLXTBLOCJMGOMK4VXNONXGGICYKBBIE7LMCTSUOVEYRAS3E2ATNQ"
    }
},
"context": {
    "System": {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.bfb81ac5-d463-4201-b70c-a35f8cc6dbed"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AHIAWE37M4SE4Q7DBFIIRLYZYXFKPU42HAD35P5XLHMZA4RGRXFERFRKPAN2I34A56TCC2XEGVNKYH7SW2KVB2NBUYAAY73GRDDXNEFFFY46W2FJXXCLSMAIUWDEUESU3ZMGIYPPYA2WXFXBBHGJBLHNVRYBLXTBLOCJMGOMK4VXNONXGGICYKBBIE7LMCTSUOVEYRAS3E2ATNQ"
        },
        "device": {
            "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AHAUYPX373VS2JXBI2E5VG4GPJPAUT5I5KRINQVJCDM7C7MZFGHWSEQV6CKKSHEZQT7HRAIAHS5BRCKLRHDDRTOE3XYWTDOSIW4MKRXAEGZIWA6XQTXY7TRC26PTPZWWB5T6D77XQNDTPLUTKRBOCJ2KLCCYRBUMXLD2GLKU4K2OQXHJDAM4Q",
            "supportedInterfaces": {}
        },
        "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
        "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.UV1qiib5UAV4msb27bxN6zBtPnaYg_1ifwWQhuSXNQpDUzM8dQlo29T5O425Itz6M-xufZT5wtJpk-mT2JZUWjdAe8bquTT9YAmAroAp3_Sa-OJ1iXP8qhiPQeu8g7Xwl2XVpFUAuaeqoSyZxzM2dnKBIND18qrcDfDTS9YRzwcrQdBaGlH-_uW0nXDOntyZ7myqB50fBVtlz5xiayHFE5J3-OTaMK4nuggMKzuL8lbYQrcEPwwbt940LiKy4CRjltHA83N1xtyBtkafcOFQPN3UAzFKPI85jUtIFuYUsuIbl7N_f64yOAgtkIQEvjCA-DWQzkerPyHJo2VrF0q7Tw"
    },
    "Viewport": {
        "experiences": [
            {
                "arcMinuteWidth": 246,
                "arcMinuteHeight": 144,
                "canRotate": false,
                "canResize": false
            }
        ],
        "shape": "RECTANGLE",
        "pixelWidth": 1024,
        "pixelHeight": 600,
        "dpi": 160,
        "currentPixelWidth": 1024,
        "currentPixelHeight": 600,
        "touch": [
            "SINGLE"
        ],
        "video": {
            "codecs": [
                "H_264_42",
                "H_264_41"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Viewports": [
        {
            "type": "APL",
            "id": "main",
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "dpi": 160,
            "presentationType": "STANDARD",
            "canRotate": false,
            "configuration": {
                "current": {
                    "video": {
                        "codecs": [
                            "H_264_42",
                            "H_264_41"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "type": "DISCRETE",
                        "pixelWidth": 1024,
                        "pixelHeight": 600
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"request": {
    "type": "LaunchRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.1d812f0b-5bce-42a6-bdd5-4791d5876e8e",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-22T09:20:12Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "shouldLinkResultBeReturned": false
}}
```

JSON Output 2:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"session": {
    "new": false,
    "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.5e3bb3da-ba51-4422-80cb-c5cace7e3756",
    "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.bfb81ac5-d463-4201-b70c-a35f8cc6dbed"
    },
    "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AHIAWE37M4SE4Q7DBFIIRLYZYXFKPU42HAD35P5XLHMZA4RGRXFERFRKPAN2I34A56TCC2XEGVNKYH7SW2KVB2NBUYAAY73GRDDXNEFFFY46W2FJXXCLSMAIUWDEUESU3ZMGIYPPYA2WXFXBBHGJBLHNVRYBLXTBLOCJMGOMK4VXNONXGGICYKBBIE7LMCTSUOVEYRAS3E2ATNQ"
    }
},
"context": {
    "System": {
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.bfb81ac5-d463-4201-b70c-a35f8cc6dbed"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AHIAWE37M4SE4Q7DBFIIRLYZYXFKPU42HAD35P5XLHMZA4RGRXFERFRKPAN2I34A56TCC2XEGVNKYH7SW2KVB2NBUYAAY73GRDDXNEFFFY46W2FJXXCLSMAIUWDEUESU3ZMGIYPPYA2WXFXBBHGJBLHNVRYBLXTBLOCJMGOMK4VXNONXGGICYKBBIE7LMCTSUOVEYRAS3E2ATNQ"
        },
        "device": {
            "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AHAUYPX373VS2JXBI2E5VG4GPJPAUT5I5KRINQVJCDM7C7MZFGHWSEQV6CKKSHEZQT7HRAIAHS5BRCKLRHDDRTOE3XYWTDOSIW4MKRXAEGZIWA6XQTXY7TRC26PTPZWWB5T6D77XQNDTPLUTKRBOCJ2KLCCYRBUMXLD2GLKU4K2OQXHJDAM4Q",
            "supportedInterfaces": {}
        },
        "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
        "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.UV1qiib5UAV4msb27bxN6zBtPnaYg_1ifwWQhuSXNQpDUzM8dQlo29T5O425Itz6M-xufZT5wtJpk-mT2JZUWjdAe8bquTT9YAmAroAp3_Sa-OJ1iXP8qhiPQeu8g7Xwl2XVpFUAuaeqoSyZxzM2dnKBIND18qrcDfDTS9YRzwcrQdBaGlH-_uW0nXDOntyZ7myqB50fBVtlz5xiayHFE5J3-OTaMK4nuggMKzuL8lbYQrcEPwwbt940LiKy4CRjltHA83N1xtyBtkafcOFQPN3UAzFKPI85jUtIFuYUsuIbl7N_f64yOAgtkIQEvjCA-DWQzkerPyHJo2VrF0q7Tw"
    },
    "Viewport": {
        "experiences": [
            {
                "arcMinuteWidth": 246,
                "arcMinuteHeight": 144,
                "canRotate": false,
                "canResize": false
            }
        ],
        "shape": "RECTANGLE",
        "pixelWidth": 1024,
        "pixelHeight": 600,
        "dpi": 160,
        "currentPixelWidth": 1024,
        "currentPixelHeight": 600,
        "touch": [
            "SINGLE"
        ],
        "video": {
            "codecs": [
                "H_264_42",
                "H_264_41"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Viewports": [
        {
            "type": "APL",
            "id": "main",
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "dpi": 160,
            "presentationType": "STANDARD",
            "canRotate": false,
            "configuration": {
                "current": {
                    "video": {
                        "codecs": [
                            "H_264_42",
                            "H_264_41"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "type": "DISCRETE",
                        "pixelWidth": 1024,
                        "pixelHeight": 600
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"request": {
    "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.30c39df8-dc26-4dcf-a193-de432a3a0ab1",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-22T09:20:13Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "reason": "ERROR",
    "error": {
        "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
        "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
    }
}}{
"body": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "response": {
        "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
    },
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "userAgent": "ask-node/2.7.0 Node/v8.15.0"
}
```

}

Comment: Can you give more information about the error, like what is the returned JSON to Alexa?

Comment: @sharankenam I added the code:)

Comment: Please add the response you are giving to the above request(launch request). Not the error response you are getting.